# Excel Export: Text Objects in title band or groupheader band get their own separate columns

Tags: delphi, excel, export, quickreports

I need to have QuickReport export to XLS files,
The problem is that I get empty columns in between my data objects,
That happens because while the stream is being created, columns are set
according to the objects position from top to bottom, in such a way that
if an objects left position is not set to the exact same position
as a detail objects left underneath it, that object will get
its own separate column, which will then result in empty cells underneath it
which can otherwise be occupied by detail objects.

An example would be: if the title was "Customer List" and the two detail columns
were "Customer Nr" and "Customer Name", the title would be placed in say B1,
then the two detail objects would receive A2 and C2. What I want though is
to for them to receive A2 and B2:

```
~~~~~~~~~|Customer List|~~~~~~~~~~~

CustNr~~~|(Empty Cell)~~|~CustName~~ ->Not good (This is what I'm getting now) :(

~~~~~~~~~|Customer List|~~~~~~~~~~~~~

CustNr~~~~|CustName~~|~~(empty Cell)} ->Good (This is the wanted result) :)
```

I was thinking theoretically, what needs to be done is to not have the
head band taken into consideration when determining the max number of columns,
but I have no idea how to achieve that.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you still use Delphi 4?

Comment: Yes, delphi4 is the developing enviorment for the source of the software marketed by my employer.

Answer (score 0):

easier solution.

create two column headers.

first column header will get 
~~~~~~~~~ Customer List ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

second column header will get 
CustNr~~~~CustName ~~~~ (empty Cell)}

each will be exported as a new line.

problem solved.